# Connect to server via VPN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, vpn, cisco-ios

I have to develop an `iPhone` application that connects to a server via `VPN`. And I believe there is no way to make `VPN connection / check for VPN connection` activity programatically. I know this is a pretty old question. And what I need to know is,

- Is there any way to connect to a VPN sever via `cisco any connect
  api` or `Juniper Clients API`?!
- Or can we invoke the VPN settings page programmatically?!